# Getting no data from mybrandnewlogo.com

Tags: python, selenium

I'm building an autonomous Selenium + Python tool to scrape logos (SVG type) to my computer but end up getting nothing when extract data

In my code, I tried to get Selenium to go through all the input steps and finally got to the logos creation page. However, after waiting for all logos to load successfully, there is no content of the text in the SVGs list

```
browser = Chrome()
browser.get('https://mybrandnewlogo.com')
sp.name_input(browser, name)

# next button
next_button = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(
        "//button[contains(text(), 'next')]")
# second phase
sp.slogan_input(browser, slogan)
next_button[0].click()
time.sleep(1)

sp.colors_input(browser, choice)

# create logos
sp.create_logos(browser)

# load
el = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, "//div[@class='js-logo-list']//div[last()]//div[@class='b-logo-card loaded']")))

# scrape data
svgs = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(
    "svg")
count = 0
for svg in svgs:
    print(svg.text)
```

I hope that I can get content of logos in SVG type exactly like in the webpage when I use ChromeDev Tools

Comment: What content exactly you want to get?

Comment: the logo is made of SVG, so I want to parse SVG code of every logo and transform them.